# miktex-xetex issue in MiKTex 2.9 portable

Tags: xetex, miktex

Compiling the example document below by means of XeLaTeX of a portable MiKTeX 2.9 installation on Win 7 resulted in the following error message:
"Unfortunately, the package miktex-xetex-base could not be installed.Please check the log file: F:/MiKTeXPortable/miktex/log/xelatex.log"

In between, the autoinstaller wants to install "fonts\misc\xetex\fontmapping\tex-text.tec" , obviously unsuccessfully.

My understanding is, according to the information given on MiKTeX' homepage ("November package refactoring"), that miktex-xetex-base has been removed and replaced by miktex-xetex and xetex packages, respectively?

Can anybody confirm this and provide (possibly) a solution?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{dinbrief}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Mapping=tex-text} 
\setmainfont{Calibri} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{url}

\setromanfont{Calibri}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\makeatletter 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\newcommand{\areacode}{}

\makeatother %% changes the catcode of @ back to 12

\address{}                     %% Kopfzeile

\signature{M. Mueller}       %% Name des Autors

\backaddress{M. Mueller, Musterweg 17, 99290 Musterstadt}
\nowindowrules                 %% Adressfensterrahmen abschalten

\renewcommand\enclname{Anlagen:}        %% Anlagenbezeichner

\pagestyle{headings} %seitenzahlen der Folgeseiten werden in Kopfzeile gedruckt

\begin{document}
 \setaddressheight {4cm}        %% Höhe des Adressfensters
 \begin{letter}{Bank AG \& Co. KGaA\\Holzweg\\10000 Musterdorf}
 \centeraddress                 %% Empfängeradresse vertikal zentrieren 

%\handling{Eilt/Persönlich}
%%%%%% Bezugszeichenzeile nach DIN 676 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\yourmail{} 
\sign{Kd.-Nr. 1000}

\writer{} %Name des Sachbearbeiters
\renewcommand{\areacode}{01234}
\phone{\areacode}{123456}
\subject{\textbf{Kündigung}\\Konto-Nr. \textbf{1000}}
\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
   Text
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
\end{letter}
\end{document}

\endinput
```

Comment: Can you install via the Package Manager?

Comment: Sounds as if your local package database is not in sync with the online database. Go to the package manager and synchronize.

Comment: OK, got it: Syncronizing with the online DB solved the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @tfran It looks like you've got two separate accounts, [tfran](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/118104/tfran) and [tfran](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/118002/tfran). The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) so you can edit all your past questions, as well as properly collect reputation and interact with the site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.